# Is there a Joomla function to determine the last fiscal quarter?

Tags: date

Just getting started with Joomla Dates - is there a convenient way to determine what the from/to dates of the last fiscal quarter are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used JDate for this, but the below PHP code works it for us:

```
// Current Date
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
list ($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $current_date);
$today = new DateTime();
$today->setDate($year, $month, $day);

// This Quarter
$month = $month % 3 ? $month + 3 - ($month % 3) : $month; //
$this_date = new DateTime();
$this_date->setDate($year, $month + 1, 0);
$thisQuarterEnd = $this_date->format('Y-m-d');
$this_date->modify('-2 month');
$this_date->modify('first day of this month');
$thisQuarterStart = $this_date->format('Y-m-d');

// Last Quarter
$last_date = clone $this_date;
$last_date->modify( '-3 month' );
$lastQuarterStart = $last_date->format('Y-m-d');
$last_date->modify( '+2 month' );
$last_date->modify('last day of this month');
$lastQuarterEnd = $last_date->format('Y-m-d');

echo '<br/>Todays Date is '.$today->format('Y-m-d');
echo '<br/>This quarter is  '.$thisQuarterStart . ' thru '.$thisQuarterEnd;
echo '<br/>LAST quarter is  '.$lastQuarterStart . ' thru '.$lastQuarterEnd;
```